Create a custom user after allauth logged in with Django
This is my project URLs.
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls'))
]

And also this is my app URLs
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home),
    path("logout", views.logout_view)
]

I have this model (very simplified)
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name

I am using allauth authentication, and I want to do some more things other than create the user when the user logs in from google, for example.

Does allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in meet your need?: https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/signals.html
